# Search versioned metadata in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

How would one go about searching for a metadata field in older versions of a node?

I know that Solr supports indexing for version2store, and it looks like in Alfresco 4.2f, it is indeed indexed. However, there does not seem to be a way to get it through the Share FTS Search by just querying :.

If this is not possible in Share search, is there something in the Java API or OpenCMIS that allows this?

Comment: For one particular node, or across all nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a query against the [Alfresco Search Service](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/search/SearchService.html) (which will in turn talk to Lucene or Solr as configured), you specify a StoreRef. Normally, that'll be `StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE` to search all current documents. However, you can equally run it against `StoreRef.PROTOCOL_ARCHIVE` to query the older versions of nodes. You can also get this from [VersionService.getVersionStoreReference()](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/version/VersionService.html#getVersionStoreReference())

When you get back the results, you should be able to look for the `versionLabel` property to see what version your result matched

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but will this respect ACLs?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly search in version store.
There is version service through which you can access particular version of document.

Then during search with Search API if you just set storeRef as version2Store it will search within that store as follow
in stores array add version2Store

```
ResultSet results = searchService.query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO, "quick");
```

This is api from searchservice

Comment: May I know what Search API are you referring to? Thank you.