# Alfresco 7: Search both in the version store and the content store

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-search-services

I have Alfresco 7.0 community edition, with search services version 2.0.2.
My need is to search for all documents having some metadata values, both in the version store  and the content store.
I've tryied to search against the versionStore from public api with the following body

```
{
    "query": {
        "language": "afts",
        "query": "TYPE:\"myc:projects\" AND myc:prop:\"pippo\""
    },
    "paging": {
        "maxItems": 100,
        "skipCount": 0
    },
    "include": [
        "allowableOperations",
        "properties"
    ],
    "scope": {
        "locations": "versions"
    }
}
```

but I get http status 500.

If I try to search from Node Browser I receive this error message `No solr query support for store workspace://version2Store`.

I also tried the ligthweigth store (which is the difference?)
[image: node browser example]

Is it possible to search with lucene, AFTS against the versions? Do I need to enable some property in alfresco-global.properties?

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212098/search-versioned-metadata-in-alfresco) and it's seems to me they can do searches.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to handle both types of searches doing a CMIS query, but I had to write a module that handle that type of reseach (the form, results to be joined and displayed...).
Versioned nodes have a property which point to the noreRef of the current node.